# on-click function not called from a directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am a beginner in Angular and i'm trying to understand why in some cases my ng-click doesnt work depending on context.
First, here's my code, then i'll try to describe more precisely my problem.

HTML :

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
   <section id="map-orders" ng-controller="ProductsController as products">
      <div class="product-box" ng-repeat="products in products.products | orderBy:'name'">
         <div class="product">
            <h3> {{products.name}} </h3>
            <span ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
</div>
```

JS :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ ]);

app.controller('ProductsController', function(){
    this.products = products;   
    this.remove = function(index) {
        products.splice(index, 1);
    }
});

var products = [
    {
        name: "Carte 1", 
        generationDate: "03/03/2016",
    },
    {
        name: "Carte 2", 
        generationDate: "04/03/2016",
    }
];
```

So this code is working. But when i transform it by adding a directive : 
HTML :

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
   <section id="map-orders" ng-controller="ProductsController as products">
      <div class="product-box" ng-repeat="products in products.products | orderBy:'name'">
         <product></product>
      </div>
   </section>
</div>
```

With this directive addiotionnaly to the original js :

```
app.directive('product', function() {
    var tpl = '<div class="product">' +
    '<h3 {{products.name}} </h3>' +
    '<span ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</span>'
    '</div>';
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
    template: tpl,
    };
});
```

My remove() function doesnt work now. I don't get why.
Can somebody help me with that? If possible specifically with my code so i get the problem.

Thank you by advance

Comment: You need to create the remove function in directive scope

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. Is there a way to call the remove function (controller) from the directive scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use **controllerAs** syntax, you need specify alias for your function `remove` in template.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/oxowjn7j/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    this.products = [{
      name: "Alex",
    }, {
      name: "Sam"
    }];
    this.remove = function(index) {
      this.products.splice(index, 1);
    }
  })
  .directive("product", function() {
    var tpl = '<div class="product">' +
      '<h3> {{product.name}} </h3>' +
      '<span ng-click="my.remove($index)">Remove</span>'
    '</div>';
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: tpl,
      link: function(scope) {
        console.log(scope);
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as my">
    <div class="product-box" ng-repeat="product in my.products">
      <product></product>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. You have mistake in template. You don't close **h3** tag

Answer (score 0):

Here your directive just uses the same scope of your `ProductsController`.So remove method in `ProductsController` can be invoked by using `products.remove($index)` since you are following `as controller` syntax while specifying controller in your html